# How can I get an IP address from a known (and fixed) MAC address using a visual studio (C++ or .net/C#) application?

Tags: ip-address, mac-address

I need to get an IP address from a known (and fixed) MAC address using a .net application. I am doing this so we can collect debug data from an embedded target in a DHCP environment where we won't know it's IP address. I've seen people say that you can ping the broadcast address of the network and then check the arp table but that does not work. I've seen people say you can query the DHCP server but that can't be done by MAC. On win7 there is no rarp anymore which AFAIK was how it should be done.

Comment: We found a different way to solve this problem (hostname supplied by embedded target at DHCP request is added by DHCP server to DNS after we enabled DNS Manager to accept insecure and secure updates). We considered the idea of broadcasting a UDP message from the target once a minute and coding the VS .net app to query the arp table for the user-supplied MAC address which would have worked but we didn't need to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Not Sure the following will help you but just try the following link

http://www.cprogramdevelop.com/1515076/

http://www.ottosiegl.at/snippets/c/arp-mit-c/

Determine IP Address From a MAC Address
http://thebackroomtech.com/2010/08/22/determine-ip-address-from-a-mac-address/